# How to convert Unix timestamp( 1541107867006) to required date time format in SAP HANA Scripted Calculation View

Tags: sql, timestamp, hana

After a good research and failing to get the required solution, I am posting the question here.

**Problem**: Unable to convert timestamp `'1541107867006'` to required date time format in SAP Scripted Calculation View.

Tried the below code and SAP functions but they work for other formats and not this specifically.

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP (ADD_SECONDS( '1970-01-01 00:00:00', '1541107867006')) TIMESTAMP,
       TO_DATE (ADD_SECONDS( '1970-01-01 00:00:00', '1541107867006')) DATE,
       TO_TIME (ADD_SECONDS( '1970-01-01 00:00:00', '1541107867006')) TIME
from DUMMY
```

Can you please help with this? Really appreciate your response!

Thanks
Supriya

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

```
TO_CHAR(ADD_SECONDS(TO_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 00:00:00'), cast('1541107867006' as bigint)/1000),'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Answer (score 1):

The constant `'1541107867006'` is not in seconds, but in milliseconds.
Try

```
SELECT ADD_SECONDS(TO_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 00:00:00'), 
    cast('1541107867006' as bigint)/1000) as "Timestamp"
from DUMMY;
```

or, because some casts are implicit:

```
SELECT ADD_SECONDS('1970-01-01 00:00:00', 
    cast('1541107867006' as bigint)/1000) as "Timestamp"
from DUMMY;
```

It's easier when the (numeric) Unix timestamp is given as a `BIGINT` right away:

```
SELECT ADD_SECONDS('1970-01-01 00:00:00', 1541107867006 / 1000) as "TimeStamp"
from DUMMY;
```